# C# constructors naming convention

Tags: c#, constructor, naming-conventions

I am new to C# and I've seen different styles to use the constructor. But some of the tutorials are over a year old. What is the best practice today?

```
class Book
{
    //Class properties
    private string title;
    private int pages;
```

Variation 1:

```
    public Book(string title, int pages)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.pages = pages;
    }
```

Variation 2:

```
    public Book(string _title, int _pages)
    {
        title = _title;
        pages = _pages;
    }
```

Variation 3:

```
    public Book(string bookTitle, int numberOfPages)
    {
        title = bookTitle;
        pages = numberOfPages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then the book I read is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most popular way

```
class Book
{
    //Class properties
    private string _title;
    private int _pages;

    public Book(string title, int pages)
    {
        _title = title;
        _pages = pages;
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm the places I worked used this pattern. Plus, that is also the way it was teached at my college.

Comment: Ok, then the book I read at the moment doesn't show the correct way... Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: One more question: I learned the underscore stands for temporary values. Is this correct?

Comment: The underscore is used to identify class level fields. As per your question those are private fields that can be accessed by any member of the class.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is the most popular way, but that does not make the book wrong. There is not just one correct way. Your variation 1 is also used often.

Comment: Fields are just another name for properties?

Comment: Not really. Fields are defined as `private string name;` where properties are defined as `public string Name {get; set;}` for instance.

Comment: I understand. Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad I could help. :)